# Apache Wicket Http Status 404 Error when changing code inside any file (java and html)

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, wicket

I'm a beginner and I'm having problem with my Apache Wicket Application. It is a Hello World Application but i added a Text box.

I was finished with the app using some tutorials and it ran perfectly but when i changed something inside the html file as well inside the java files. I get the HTTP Status 404 error. I found a fix that you have to change the Compiler Compliance Level to something other than the current level. Then if you run it it will run perfectly again but if you change something again it will give the same error. Im using tomcat as the servlet.

I have to change and change the level to make it work again. Can someone help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Wicket</display-name>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Application</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
      <param-value>com.ibm.app.HelloWorldApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Application</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I have this html file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">

<head>
<style>

label {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 102px;
}

.feedbackPanelERROR {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
   <h1 wicket:id="greeting">This is greeting from web page.</h1>

    <h1>Creating a Text Box</h1>

    <div wicket:id="feedback"></div>
    <form wicket:id="userForm">
        <p>
            <label>Username</label>: 
            <input wicket:id="username" type="text" size="20" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The java files are a combination of the Quickstart hello world tutorial and this tutorial

http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-textbox-example/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the official quick start of Apache Wicket. You can find it [here](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html). It is really easy to get your application up and running in five simple steps.